# Why support the support tag?

Tags: discussion

Why is there a [support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/support) tag ? What is it for ?

Is it a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of the 88 questions currently tagged [support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/support), it seems to be used to say "I need help", "Does Ubuntu *support* this", and "Canonical Paid services". For the first two, it's a meta tag. As for the last meaning [ubuntu-advantage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-advantage) would be a better tag. So in true fluish fashion, this tag is evil and needs to be removed.

Comment: Haven't there already been a ton of requests to salt the tag previously?  I could have sworn this was on my list of tags to salt when I last made a post about tags...  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salting_the_earth for "Salt" definition)